# In Xampp Apache and MySQL is not starting

Tags: mysql, xampp

I reinstall windows 10 when I open Xampp Apache and MySQL was not starting it was showing error then I reinstall xampp but now apache and MySQL is just stuck on preparing to start

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall it and check if the folder is still in C:/

Comment: Try it on C folder. Should work there.

Comment: Did you install it in the root directory of your drive?

Comment: For example: "C://" the directory is the main folder

Comment: Yea I downloaded there

Comment: Install it in the directory and see if shows any errors

Comment: I downloaded there also having error

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: All right, good work